# SVG not drawn outside the visible area of Google Maps

Tags: css, html, google-maps, svg, d3.js

I used Mike Bostok's [example](http://bl.ocks.org/899711) for using d3 with Google Maps for showing a contour plot. Here is my code:

http://bl.ocks.org/4959573

Everything seems fine, except that the contour plot doesn't get drawn outside the visible area of the Google Map. I managed to fix this by playing with the dimensions of the map:

```
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3000px;
  top: -1000px;
}
```

This is not optimal and doesn't solve the problem completely since, if I zoom in too much, the size of the plot will rapidly exceed the size of the map and panning the map will make it visible.

Is there any other way to fix it?

Comment: I found a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12027910/2075184

I changed the map style to:


    `#map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }`

The style of the contour layer got modified like this:

    `cont_layer
     .attr("width","8000px")
     .attr("height","8000px")
     .style("position","absolute")
     .style("top","-4000px")
     .style("left","-4000px"); `

x and y coordinates of the SVG paths have to be shifted by +4000px to compensate. My git code reflects these changes now.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Since it's a duplicate, shouldn't it be deleted ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overlay d3 paths onto Google Maps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909099/overlay-d3-paths-onto-google-maps)

Answer (score 1):

*OP's solution to their own problem, quoted and reformatted from the comments:*

I changed the map style to:

```
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

The style of the contour layer got modified like this:

```
cont_layer
    .attr("width","8000px")
    .attr("height","8000px")
    .style("position","absolute")
    .style("top","-4000px")
    .style("left","-4000px");
```

x and y coordinates of the SVG paths have to be shifted by +4000px to compensate.