# D3 + Google Maps + Paths + Labels Bug witih Panning and Zooming

Tags: google-maps, d3.js, overlay, projection, label

I am D3 newbie. My goal was to create a map, draw an SVG layer on top of it with areas defined and then label those areas.

There is a bug with the labels. I can successfully add them but when I pan and zoom they don't move with the map. I have a feeling it has something to do with the 'x' and 'y' values determined for the text labels, but I am not sure what the values should be.

```
adminDivisions.selectAll("text")
.data(geoJson.features)
.enter()
.append("text")
.text(function(d){
   return d.properties.title;
})
.attr("x",function(d){
   return path.centroid(d)[0];
})
.attr("y", function(d){
   return path.centroid(d)[1];
});
```

My code is based off of this: [Overlay d3 paths onto Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909099/overlay-d3-paths-onto-google-maps)
and this: [Add names of the states to a map in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897534/add-names-of-the-states-to-a-map-in-d3-js)

JSFiddle with sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/vZmrZ/

Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 5):

I figured out the answer! The x and y attributes needed to be called twice, once before 'entering' and once after 'entering' so that it gets updated whenever the map moves. No more panning and zooming issues :)

```
adminDivisions.selectAll("text")
                    .data(geoJson.features)
                    .attr("x",function(d){
                        return path.centroid(d)[0];                         
                    })
                    .attr("y", function(d){
                        return path.centroid(d)[1];                         
                    }) 
                    .enter()                        
                    .append("text")
                    .text(function(d){
                        return d.properties.name;
                    })
                    .attr("x",function(d){
                        return path.centroid(d)[0];                         
                    })
                    .attr("y", function(d){
                        return path.centroid(d)[1];

                    });
```

Updated fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/vZmrZ/1/