# D3 overlay on google maps not fully rendering

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, d3.js, google-maps-api-3

as background, I've been working on a small project highlighting local neighborhoods and crime incidents over time in a d3 overlay on a google map, but finding that my overlay only partially renders.

The initial objective is achieving something visually like the map rendered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909099/overlay-d3-paths-onto-google-maps).

The code for the this target/example map can be seen in the [JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vjxpr/). I've used this example to guide my current work.

Unfortunately, when I run my overlay code with a google map for the view I'm targeting, I find that only small portions of the overall d3 paths actually render on the google map. From debugging in the console, I can see that all the relevant geojson data is loading and each path array is being included as a path node, but only one or two of the paths is being displayed on the map - e.g. I only see transparent fill over one or two neighborhoods (as shown in image linked below).

[View of map's partial overlay rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI2n9.png)

Can anyone advise on why the d3 overlay with geojson data isn't being fully displayed, and how I can fix this, so that I see the full neighborhoods overlay?

Code below, and many thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
      function draw(geo_data) {
        "use strict";
        var margin = 100,
            width = 1400 - margin,
            height = 1000 - margin;

        var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

        overlay.onAdd = function() {

          var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div")
                        .attr("class", "SvgOverlay");

          var svg = layer.append("svg");
          var neighborhoods = svg.append("g").attr("class", "Neighborhoods");

          overlay.draw = function(){
            var markerOverlay = this;
            var overlayProjection = markerOverlay.getProjection();

            var googleMapProjection = function (coordinates) {
              var googleCoordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[1], coordinates[0]);
              var pixelCoordinates = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(googleCoordinates);
              return [pixelCoordinates.x, pixelCoordinates.y]; 
            };

            path = d3.geo.path().projection(googleMapProjection);
            neighborhoods.selectAll("path")
                        .data(geo_data.features)
                        .enter()
                        .append("path")
                        .attr("d", path);
          };                        
        };
        overlay.setMap(google_base);
      };
      </script>
  </head>
<body>

  <div id="google_map">
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var google_base = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#google_map").node(), {
      zoom: 13,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.81, -122.26),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      zoomControl: false,
      styles:[{"stylers": [{"saturation": -50},{"lightness": 75}]}]
    });

    d3.json("neighborhoods.geojson", draw);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: example geojson data

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "NAME": "Montclair" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -122.21594888924534, 37.832181779651613 ], [ -122.199005320235656, 37.839802502024263 ], [ -122.195700218341074, 37.834717626248832 ], [ -122.204865526096057, 37.83063877524836 ], [ -122.204065506384751, 37.826138894083272 ], [ -122.203989505503827, 37.825037923657973 ], [ -122.204862534763905, 37.82484093266519 ], [ -122.206357582839033, 37.825825912182573 ], [ -122.207037605809575, 37.825554922390438 ], [ -122.21045471226752, 37.829664825068207 ], [ -122.212788791761739, 37.828300871884338 ], [ -122.21104273740049, 37.826278919502776 ], [ -122.209740697282683, 37.824438964026321 ], [ -122.209719696572449, 37.824446963720987 ], [ -122.207737635353567, 37.821578033328542 ], [ -122.207938642362265, 37.821377039630789 ], [ -122.208037645976759, 37.82117704547791 ], [ -122.208238653148413, 37.820877054469094 ], [ -122.210140719787248, 37.818876116804304 ], [ -122.211442762016475, 37.819577103232504 ], [ -122.212243787852969, 37.820077093014056 ], [ -122.214446859285928, 37.821177072378525 ], [ -122.215348888403369, 37.821678062551726 ], [ -122.216549926889712, 37.822478045852897 ], [ -122.216749933170547, 37.822678041257156 ], [ -122.217351952809793, 37.822878038347341 ], [ -122.218401986194451, 37.823679020982773 ], [ -122.221157073570424, 37.825778975452437 ], [ -122.222459113734274, 37.827279940103317 ], [ -122.222759122864446, 37.827679930485409 ], [ -122.223861155874616, 37.829379888880801 ], [ -122.224462173475956, 37.830480861460941 ], [ -122.223133128544632, 37.830996841877365 ], [ -122.222659112528717, 37.83118083489429 ], [ -122.221358066237769, 37.83288178322033 ], [ -122.219555006623537, 37.832981772972666 ], [ -122.218852983299286, 37.833081767323314 ], [ -122.217851950689095, 37.832881768578396 ], [ -122.217351934210413, 37.832881766490274 ], [ -122.21594888924534, 37.832181779651613 ] ] ] } }
```

Comment: The line `.attr("d", path);` looks suspect when you've just bound data. Did you mean to pass a function?

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Anko. I don't think this is the root of the problem, as this is updating existing paths, not the bound data, and is aslo the approach in the example I've been following, as well as an example from mbostock [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/899711), but perhaps path needs to be replaced with a function call for each path element - will investigate.